# why is input.value undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JavaScript to grab the value of an input, however, the input is coming back as undefined. I originally put the row in using insertrow and a variable. The row uses a variable as its value because each row is different. Later I call the add section to try and add up all of the numbers in a given column. However, when I call the function and the alert comes back it simply says undefined yet in the actual table on the page the value is there. Why is the value coming back as undefined?

```js
var myHtmlContent = "<tr><td>" + dwgno + "</td><td>" 
+ desc + "</td><td>" 
+ prof + "</td><td>" 
+ piec + "</td><td>" 
+ len + "</td><td>" 
+ ibft + "</td><td>" 
+ obs + "</td><td><input type='number' value=" + bud + "></input></td>" +
"<td><input type='number' value=" + mscmat + "></input></td>" +
"<td><input type='number' value=" + galfin + "></input></td>" +
"<td><input type='number' value=" + fab3 + "></input></td>" +
"<td><input type='number' value=" + ins3 + "></input></td>" +
"<td><input type='number' value=" + ins4 + "></input></td>" +
"</td></tr>"
var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTablesecond').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
newRow.innerHTML = myHtmlContent;

// add function:
var table = document.getElementById("myTablesecond");
            
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        alert(row.cells[7].value);
        total+=parseFloat(row.cells[7].innerhtml) || 0;
    }
```

Comment: A cell (`row.cells[7]`) doesn't have a value, but its element(s) seem to here. Try `row.cells[7].querySelector("input").value`

Comment: Why would a TD have a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input>` elements have `value`s, `<td>` elements do not. `row.cells` is a collection of the latter.

You might be looking for `row.cells[7].children[0].value`

Nothing has an `innerhtml`. The property is `innerHTML`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you it has apparently been a long day and i did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is really not right here. There is no reason to write all that HTML as strings to be concatenated with variables. Instead, hard code the HTML you know you'll need and just supply content to the elements as needed. In many cases, this will allow you to avoid using `innerHTML` (not `innerhtml`) as [`.innerHTML` has security and performance implications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and should be avoided when possible.

Keep in mind that `input` elements do not get closing tags and that non-form elements don't have a `value`, they have `textContent`.

Lastly, while I have shown my example using tables (as you have shown in your question), be aware that you should not be using tables for layout purposes (use CSS for that). Tables are only for displaying tabular data.

```js
// Declare and initialize variables
let dwgno = "lorem";
let desc = "ipsum";
let prof = "tollas";
let piec = "verdam";
let len = "vollet";
let ibft = "tolar";
let obs = "sipsum";
let bud = 1;
let mscmat = 2;
let galfin = 3;
let fab3 = 4;
let ins3 = 5;
let ins4 = 6;

// populate inputs
document.querySelector("#dwgno").textContent = dwgno;
document.querySelector("#desc").textContent = desc;
document.querySelector("#prof").textContent = prof;
document.querySelector("#piec").textContent = piec;
document.querySelector("#len").textContent = len;
document.querySelector("#ibft").textContent = ibft;
document.querySelector("#obs").textContent = obs;
document.querySelector("#bud").value = bud;
document.querySelector("#mscmat").value = mscmat;
document.querySelector("#galfin").value = galfin;
document.querySelector("#fab3").value = fab3;
document.querySelector("#ins3").value = ins3;
document.querySelector("#ins4").value = ins4;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="dwgno"></span></td>
    <td><span id="desc"></span></td>
    <td><span id="prof"></span></td>
    <td><span id="piec"></span></td>
    <td><span id="len"></span></td>
    <td><span id="ibft"></span></td>    
    <td><span id="obs"></span></td>       
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="bud"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="mscmat"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="galfin"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="fab3"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="ins3"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="ins4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well it has to be written that way as many rows are being added into a table and that is how I am adding them. The insert row shows that and there is info I am pulling from another table above this code, so hardcoding would not be an option.

Comment: @GizmoDailys Even so, you can use [HTML Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). Your approach is what we did about 25+ years ago.

Comment: That is very cool and helpful thank you. I am teaching myself all of this so I appreciate that.